# How do I access the built-in dictionaries on iOS without hitting "Define..."?

Tags: ios

Right now, when I need to check a word in the dictionary, I open Notes, type in something, select the word and hit "Define..."

I'd like to directly type in a word and check something, similar to how I can just type stuff into Spotlight & look up definitions in OS X.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old thread, but I think it's worth noting that Spotlight on iOS 11 has a built-in dictionary widget - you can type in any word and scroll down to see the dictionary. And Spotlight itself is accesible from any Home screen page.

Comment: Finally the devs got around to it huh ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Now I need to figure out how to show other language words defined in English if that's at all possible :-P

Comment: @AdityaMP you can add any of the built-in international dictionaries (personally, I've added the standard German dictionary and the English-German dictionary and both work just fine), because the widget shows all activate dictionaries (you can tap 'see more' to show all of them in the widget).

Comment: Indeed! I disabled the !language dictionary and enabled !language-English version, and it is perfect :’-) thank you!!

Answer (score 7):

This is currently not possible. Apple also [forbids third party developers to create a simple wrapper around the dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIReferenceLibraryViewControllerClassRef/), which means that there will probably not be any applications that do just that. There are, however, several other third party dictionaries which are quite good.

> A UIReferenceLibraryViewController object provides a dictionary service to look up the definition of a word or term from within an app. It should not be used to display wordlists, create a standalone dictionary app, or republish the content in any form.

According to this answer [Can iOS' builtin dictionary be accessed/browsed as an independent app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104401/can-ios-builtin-dictionary-be-accessed-browsed-as-an-independent-app) you can download the application DictionaryPlusPlus, which does just that, here https://github.com/josh-/DictionaryPlusPlus, it is open source and you will have to compile and sign it yourself.

Comment: Wow. Any idea why it's this way?

Comment: Probably because Apple does not want the App Store to be swarmed by easy to make dictionary apps. Anyways, according to this answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104401/can-ios-builtin-dictionary-be-accessed-browsed-as-an-independent-app there is an open source iOS app that does just that. However you will have to compile and sign it yourself.

Comment: Excellent I will use this open source app! I have a dev certificate. Could you perhaps update your answer to include this information?

Answer (score 1):

I use DictBox to see dictionary entries that I look up.  It is a multidictionary app, and also lets you see what the iOs dictionary says about the word.  I find the Apple dictionary to have the best definitions actually and the most excellent etymology included.  The dictionary alone on the apple products are worth something.